# Java: Image won't show until I resize the window

Tags: java, image, user-interface, resize, jpanel

I am programming in java and I'm getting into GUIs and Graphics. In my program I paint an image onto a JPanel and add the JPanel to the main window. The Problem I'm having is when I run the program the image doesn't show until I manually resize the window. Here is the relevant code:

Where the image is drawn:

```
public class painting extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image.png"), 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Where JPanel is added to JFrame (c is GridBagConstraints):

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    public GUI(){
        painting Pnt = new painting();
        c.gridx = 1;    c.gridy = 0;
        c.ipadx = 540;  c.ipady = 395;
        add(Pnt, c);        
    }
}
```

Where The Window is set up:

```
public class MainC{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("Title");
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Bennett

EDIT: I noiced that it sometimes displays the image correctly but then if I close the program and try again and it doesn't work until I resize it.

EDIT2: Here are the files [GUI class](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8813945/GUI.java), [MainC class](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8813945/MainC.java)

Comment: @Mr. Giggums, what's the purpose of invoking `setBackground(...)`? Also, you should not be loading images inside `paintComponent(...)`.

Comment: You might want to try using the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Though note that I suspect the problem will be fixed if you implement the advice provided by mre & myself.

Comment: I finally got it to work using ImageIO.read(). Thank you every one for helping me out.

Comment: Just to expand on Chris' advice, make sure you create (& update) GUI elements *on* the EDT.  Not doing so can result in occasional rendering bugs & exceptions.  That `main(String[])` is clearly constructing the GUI *off* the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: @Mr. Giggums, I hope you still don't read the image in the paintComponent() method. You don't want to keep reading the image every time the component needs to be repainted. Also, why are you even doing custom painting? Just use a JLabel which was designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Toolkit.getImage()` works asynchronously.  Either use `ImageIO.read()` or add a `MediaTracker`.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. +1 for reporting back.

Comment: +1, for describing the problem and prescribing a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

In `GUI` constructor you should call super() before anything else.

Also move:

```
gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gui.pack();
gui.setVisible(true);
gui.setTitle("Title");
```

in GUI constructor.

Comment: I tried it and it still is not working. I can get the Jframe and the JPanel to show but the picture is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

does

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image.png")
```

brings you the picture?

I tried it with:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
public Gui() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel(){
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            try {
                g.drawImage(new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(90, 90)), 0, 0, null);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    getContentPane().add(pnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Gui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

and it works.

Comment: Yes Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image.png") will bring me my picture.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be somewhere else in your code. I copied and pasted your three classes into my IDE. The only thing I changed was in GUI.java I added `setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` and `GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();` and I changed the location of the image to one of my own. The window works as expected with the image displayed right away.

I assume you have additional code not displayed here, such as the initialization of c that I added. Check your other code to make sure you are not redrawing over your image initially. Also, if you post the other code I could help you identify the problem

Comment: I did initialzed c and I don't have any more code in my painting class but Do have more code in my GUI constructor. But as far as I can tell it doesn't mess anything up. Also I can get it to work every once in a while but when I close the window and retry it doesn't work.

Comment: would you mind just posting all your code? I can't reproduce the your problem right now so it's hard to debug.

Comment: Code is now in my main post at the links on the bottom.